# Sonoff basic- GPIO’s

Tags: hardware, esp8266

As far as I found documented- there are GPIOS 0, 12, 13, 14 on a basic Sonoff.

Does anyone know if Tx/Rx are free to use after uploading my code, as GPIO’s ?

Answer (score 2):

I had used Sonoff for some time. Yes RX and TX pins are used while programming ESP8266 inside the Sonoff. But After the flashing/programming, you are completely free to use those pins.

Comment: Hi- thank you for your reply. picture attached is not sonoff basic, BUTmore important - Is for sonoff BASIC Tx or Rx are GPIO15 ? which one of them ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong upload. Sonoff Basic main line has 5 pins - 3v3, Rx, Tx, GND, and GPIO14. I don't exactly know about GPIO15. But you can refer [Randomnerdtutorials.](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/how-to-flash-a-custom-firmware-to-sonoff/) That's what I referred during my project using sonoff.

Comment: Tx/Rx was not switched as GPIO15